# How to not display a heads up notification when own app is in use?

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I'm working on an android application where i need to show a time-sensitive notification in a specific situation.

Normaly our app is running in the background and when the phone is in use the heads up notification is displayed correctly and when the user interacts with it, the correct activity is started.

When the phone is not in use (e.g. locked) the fullScreenIntent works and the correct activity is started.

In the case the user is working with our app at the moment the notification appears, i would like to lead directly to the activity i set as the fullScreenIntent. But at the moment also the head up notification is shown and the activity doesn't start automatically. Is there a way i can make my activity to be started when our app is currently being used by the user?

I build my notification like this and it is used for a foreground service.

```
    val pendingCancelIntent = getCancelPendingIntent()
    val pendingFinishIntent = getFinishPendingIntent()
    val fullScreenPendingIntent = getFullScreenPendingIntent()

    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.title))
        .setContentText(getString(R.string.text))
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
        .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true)

    notificationBuilder.addAction(
        R.drawable.ic_cancel,
        getString(R.string.general_cancel),
        pendingCancelIntent
    )
    notificationBuilder.addAction(
        R.drawable.ic_finish,
        getString(R.string.finish),
        pendingFinishIntent
    )

    notificationBuilder.build()
```

Comment: "In the case the user is working with our app at the moment the notification appears" -- what is your trigger for showing the notification? You could update that to take the foreground/background status of your UI into account (see `ProcessLifecycleOwner`).

Comment: In the app the user can record a trip and in the case something happens another service will be started and here the notification comes in place. In the past we just started an activity but since Android 10, this isn't possible anymore. I know that i can check if the app is in foreground or not. I was wondering if there is a setting i can use building the notification.

Comment: "I was wondering if there is a setting i can use building the notification" -- I do not recall an option for that, sorry.